# Object #<HTMLHeadingElement> has no method 'fadeOut'

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, every function i'm calling is not working. Either it is "fadeOut", "fadeIn" or "fadeTo", I am getting the error.

Here is the js script code as well as the HTML.

```
<html>
    <head>    
        <script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"> 
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello world</h1>

        <ol>
            <li> Hello</li>
            <li> My </li>
            <li> Name </li>
            <li> is </li>
        </ol>

    </body>
</html>


$(document).ready(function(){

    $('ol li').click(function(){
        this.fadeOut('slow');
    });

    $('h1').click(function(){
        this.fadeOut('slow',0.5);
    });

    $('li:nth-child(1)').mouseenter(function(){
        ('li:nth-child(2)').fadeOut('slow',0.25);
    });

});
```

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you

Comment: `$('li:nth-child(2)')`. ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to call jQuery methods on objects that aren't jQuery ones. So `this` becomes `$(this)`, etc.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('ol li').click(function()
    {
        $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    });

    $('h1').click(function()
    {
        $(this).fadeOut('slow',0.5);
    });

    $('li:nth-child(1)').mouseenter(function()
    {
        $('li:nth-child(2)').fadeOut('slow',0.25);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ahh I forgot the $ sign. Feel so dumb now...Thx!